# How to add array as post parameter retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, laravel-5.1

I want to pass an array as parameter like this:

```
images[] = "Base64String A..."
images[] = "Base64String B..." 
images[] = "Base64String C..."
images[] = "Base64String ..."
```

I'm using Laravel 5.1 on server side.
My controller to handle post data:

```
public function uploadTempImage(){
    if (Input::has('images')) {
        $images = Input::get('images'); 
        $barcode_id =Input::get('barcode_id'); 
        $upload_count=0;
        foreach($images as $string_image) {         
            $image = base64_decode($string_image);        
            $filename = "$barcode_id$upload_count".time().date("d").date("m").date("Y").".jpeg";                
            $upload_count +=Storage::disk('local')->put("/tempImage/".$filename ,  $image);
        }
        return $upload_count;
    }else{
        return 'no file uploaded';
    }


}
```

i use postman to test my server and its working..

[image]

please help me get over this.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** using arrays in form data like this is a bit problematic and hardly standardized. Avoid if possible.

**Long version**

Read [this issue on retrofit's github](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/490)

If the strings won't be too massive, consider using JSON as your transport vehicle, and declare a JSON array to store your base64 strings.

Comment: thank you .. i think this is the only way... no choice thanks anyway